# 100% usage on one of the cores caused by moving the laptop around

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xorg

Whenever I move the laptop, like put it aside and get up from the couch (or lie down on the couch and take it), something starts fully loading one of the cores causing everything to lag and stutter miserably.
Only solution I've been able to find so far is rebooting the system. Then it works fine until I move the laptop again. Restarting gdm/lightdm switching from lightdm to gdm and vice versa doesn't help.
I thought it might have been caused by the NVIDIA drivers but switching back to open source drivers doesn't fix the issue.

Is there any way I can diagnose what's causing this behaviour? I tried disabling the accelerometer module but that doesn't seem to help at all.

The notebook is a Hp pavilion 15-cs2025ur with a NVIDIA GeForce MX250 dedicated graphics adapter running Ubuntu 20.04 (Recently upgraded from 18.04, the bug's there on 18.04 as well). I'm using proprietary drivers for the graphics adapter - nvidia-driver-440.

[image]
[image]

Edit: I tried restarting gnome by

- Pressing Alt-F2, typing r and hitting enter
- sudo systemctl restart gdm
- sudo systemctl restart lightdm

All of these except for the first one lead me to the login page, but the anomalous load on one of the CPU cores (or rather threads) remains.
I generally have no idea where or what logs should I look into, I saw a suggestion to check /var/log/Xorg.0.log somewhere and I saw this being spammed over and over again

```
[   144.226] (WW) modeset(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[   144.226] (WW) modeset(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
[   144.226] (EE) modeset(0): present flip failed
```

But it doesn't happen all the time, as in sometimes the system clearly is in the faulty state but Xorg.0.log (and Xorg.1.log) files don't contain the aforementioned errors.

Comment: Have you tried to see if this also happens in a live system on a usb (maybe even try different flavours)? to me this sounds like something with the hardware, maybe a short or something loosing contact. Also may I suggest to simply restart gnome-shell and not the entire system. If you decide to try any of this please add any output or logs to your question.

Comment: I have very little idea where or what logs to look into for possible clues, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.  
I will check whether the issue is reproducible in a LiveCD environment, however I've had this issue even before I upgraded from 18.04.  
Also, I've edited the post with ways I've tried restarting gnome shell and the only bit of suspicious log entries I've been able to find.